# Kivy app packaged with Buildozer crashes on Android

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer

I packaged my Kivy app for Android using buildozer. It seems to run pretty much fine, however the app crashes at random moments (at least random to me). What seems to trigger the crashes more often is when I change screens (I am using ScreenManager). These crashes do not happen when I simply run the python scripts on my laptop, so the problem seems to be Android-specific.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/j1ae0UjD) is my log. I copied only the last part as pastebin does not let me copy the whole file. The error should occur around 15:15:29. Please let me know if you need to see more.

Also, I see many lines in the log file refering to facebook, for example:

```
06-15 15:15:28.480 25348 25418 I m.facebook.orc:   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
06-15 15:15:28.480 25348 25418 I m.facebook.orc:   at java.lang.Object X.0g4.A0D(int, X.0eM) (:201)
06-15 15:15:28.480 25348 25418 I m.facebook.orc:   at java.lang.Object X.0g4.A00(int, X.0eM) (:60)
06-15 15:15:28.480 25348 25418 I m.facebook.orc:   at java.lang.Object X.0fE.A00(int, X.0eM) (:55)
06-15 15:15:28.480 25348 25418 I m.facebook.orc:   at java.lang.Object X.0jo.next() (:43)
06-15 15:15:28.480 25348 25418 I m.facebook.orc:   at void com.facebook.push.init.PushInitializer.A02() (:29)
```

what does facebook have to do with my Kivy app?

Comment: I think you might have hit a Kivy bug that is fixed in more recent versions of Kivy and/or python-for-android.

Comment: Also the logcat is a generic output stream, the facebook stuff has nothing to do with yuor app.

Comment: I have the latest version of Kivy (1.11.1). However, I could not check my p4a version. ```p4a --version```  does not find any command named p4a.

Comment: any other hints?